# How can I download all queries made in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have created a small DataStudio dashboard that consumes BigQuery data from a quite large table - 4.5 GB today, increasing daily.

It was a hit today, which increased my average GCS cost in five times in one day. How can I download the full list of queries done so I can check details on usage?

By the way, if you have ideas on how to reduce the query cost, please do share. I've already reduced the amount of columns used to build the results, and I'm thinking of ways of further reducing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

To view your query history, click the Query history tab in BigQuery console. To see the details of a query, select the query from the query history list.

The job and query histories in the Cloud Console include all load, export, copy, and query jobs that you submitted in the past 6 months (up to 1,000 entries). The limit of 1,000 jobs is cumulative across all job types.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#viewing_job_and_query_history

[image]

**Option 2:**

If you like to see more than 1000 queries, we can use the audit logs. Use the following filter in logs explorer

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.getqueryresults"
```

Comment: Yes, but what happens is I've had a few thousand queries in one day and only the most recent were reachable on the project history

Comment: @MarceloSoares Please check the edited answer